# Whats the best way of extracting a specific number in a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, split

When given a string in a format such as this:

`Randy Test 10000 1 aValue 3.5mL bValue 4.0mL`

What's the best way to parse through and take `3.5` and `4.0` and set them to integers?

One way I thought of was to split based on "." since both values will always have a decimal and take the first and last value of each array. I also know regex expressions might help in this field but I don't have any experience with regulars expressions.

Comment: First of all, 3.5 and 4.0 aren't integers so don't try to set them as one. Second, if you don't have any experience with Regex you should go find a tutorial and try some code. We aren't here to make a Regex for you or teach you how to use them.

Comment: Integers? 3.5? Don't you mean doubles?

Comment: Is the string literally always like this, with data in this order? If so, you can split on the spaces and pretend you have a tokenizer and take the 6th and 8th things. That's dicey though and assumes you always have this data, but maybe that's valid depending on where it comes from. The 6th and 8th things then just need split on the period to get the leading number. Assuming they always have one and you don't need rounding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exp = new RegEx("([0-9.]{1,5})mL");
var input = "Randy Test 10000 1 aValue 3.5mL bValue 4.0mL";

var results = (exp.Matches(input) as IEnumerable<Match>).
                  Select(m => Double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Or if you want to get more specific:

```
var exp = new RegEx("[ab]Value ([0-9.]{1,5})mL");
var input = "Randy Test 10000 1 aValue 3.5mL bValue 4.0mL";

var results = (exp.Matches(input) as IEnumerable<Match>).
                  Select(m => Double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
```